# Is there a way to Ungroup group by data

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like to ungroup the dataframe after applying group by condition.
I used pandas group by & sum to group by. Following is group by table

```
+------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+
|   Month    | Amt_8_red_17 | Amt_8_black_29 | Amt_10_black_29 |
+------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+
| 01-01-2018 |            0 |             12 |              18 |
| 01-02-2018 |          100 |             12 |              12 |
+------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

Now I want to ungroup the data. The column names are the combination of columns joined by underscore.
eg: Amt_8_red_17 : column names are (Amount,Count,Color,Id)
The output looks like

```
+------------+---------+-------+-------+----+
|   Month    | Amount  | Count | Color | Id |
+------------+---------+-------+-------+----+
| 01-01-2018 |       0 |     8 | red   | 17 |
| 01-01-2018 |      12 |     8 | black | 29 |
| 01-01-2018 |      18 |    10 | black | 29 |
| 01-02-2018 |     100 |     8 | red   | 17 |
| 01-02-2018 |      12 |     8 | black | 29 |
| 01-02-2018 |      12 |    10 | black | 29 |
+------------+---------+-------+-------+----+
```

Is there any faster way?

Comment: A faster way to what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create index by all columns without `_` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) if necessary.

Then create `MultiIndex` by [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html).

Last data cleaning - remove first level by first [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), second is for columns from `MultiIndex`. Last set new columns names.

```
df = df.set_index('Month')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.unstack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index()
df.columns= ['Count','Color','Id','Month','Amount']
print (df)
  Count  Color  Id       Month  Amount
0     8    red  17  01-01-2018       0
1     8    red  17  01-02-2018     100
2     8  black  29  01-01-2018      12
3     8  black  29  01-02-2018      12
4    10  black  29  01-01-2018      18
5    10  black  29  01-02-2018      12
```

Last if necessary change order columns:

```
df = df[['Month','Amount','Count','Color','Id']]
print (df)
        Month  Amount Count  Color  Id
0  01-01-2018       0     8    red  17
1  01-02-2018     100     8    red  17
2  01-01-2018      12     8  black  29
3  01-02-2018      12     8  black  29
4  01-01-2018      18    10  black  29
5  01-02-2018      12    10  black  29
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael